# Get Moments of user in Wechat

Tags: wechat

My goal is to get all moments of some user using public API. I've found this [documentaion](https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/en/dev/api/), but, as I understood, it is aimed to creating `Mini Programs`, which doesn't suit me. The most desirable way is just to send one request with user's credentials. Is it even possible, and if it is, how do I approach it?

Comment: Same for me, stumbling upon trying to get user's moments feeds for social feeds, but still no breakthrough. Any update?

Comment: @MuhammadKamal sorry for the late answer. No, there's no update whatsoever. I guess it is just not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for what's possible on the web side of things (no MiniProgram), you need to refer tot the Official Account Documentation (https://developers.weixin.qq.com/doc/offiaccount/en/Getting_Started/Overview.html).
As far as I am aware, only public information of users can be retrieved, and it does not include their Moments.

Comment: Sorry, haven't been here for a while. Yes, as I understand, there is no way to do that, so I'll accept this answer